# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I am getting "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'employee' is defined" error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please find below the code.

1. ) AppConfig Class:

   ```
   @ComponentScan("com.spring.annotation.propertyconfigurer")
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:employee.properties")
   public class AppConfig {

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }    
   }
   ```

2) Employee Class

```
@Component("employee")
public class Employee {

    @Value("${emp.empId}")
    private int empId;
    @Value("${emp.name}")
    private String name;
    @Autowired
    private Address address;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Employee Id -> " + empId);
        System.out.println("Employee Name -> " + name);
        System.out.println("Employee Address -> [ " + address.getCity() + "," + getAddress().getCountry() + "]");
    }
}
```

3) Address Class:

```
@Component("address")
public class Address {

    private String city;
    private String country;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

4) Main Class

```
public class PropertyConfigurerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("AppConfig.class")) {
            Employee employee = (Employee) context.getBean("employee");
            employee.print();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

---

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

You've to register your beans to the configuration, for example using Component Scanning on packages of your Components.

There are several ways to do this

- via xml config   `<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>`
- using `@ComponentScan({package1, .., package n})` in your `@Configuration`

You can also add a `@Bean` for your `@Components` in your `@Configuration`

See spring documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config

HOW TO CHANGE YOUR CODE

1- give to your classes a package (if you didn't it already). I Used test.component for the employee and address

2- in AppConfig change

```
     @ComponentScan("com.spring.annotation.propertyconfigurer")
```

with

```
    @ComponentScan("test.component")
```

or

```
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"test.component"})
```

3- In propertyConfigurerApp change

```
            AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("AppConfig.class")
```

with

```
  AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class)
```

It should work (put your employee.properties on root of classpath)

However you didn't need to make all this componentscanning stuffs as you don't use autowiring in your example.

Comment: @Massino I already have ComponentScan in my AppCongif class. So it should work.

Comment: Also, I have registered the Employee and Address class a spring bean using @Component. But still its not working

Comment: You didn't set @ComponentScan({package-where-your-components-are}).Also you should don't need  @ComponentScan("com.spring.annotation.propertyconfigurer) as you defined as bean

Comment: Ok. So, after looking my code where you suggest me to put @Component-scan.

Comment: you've to put it in AppConfig

Comment: I have put ComponentScan annotation in AppConfig only. Please check my code.